# Is it possible to link a debug mode compiled library to a project in release mode?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a compiled library (static .lib) in debug mode in C++ and Visual Studio and want to use it in a project which is going to be compiled in release mode. Is this possible? I couldn't compile the library in the release mode :(
Let me ask a little bit more general question: what considerations should I care about working with libraries?

Comment: If the .lib links to the same runtime as the project then you are fine. But it probably doesn't. You should compile the library in for release rather than for debug.

Comment: What version of visual studio? Do you get linker errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to link a debug mode complied library to a project in release mode?

Yes. Debug mode only means there are assertions, debug symbols included, etc. The debug version of the library should be fully functional just like the release version (although it might run slower/consume more memory than a release build).

Edit: as David Rodriguez-dribeas points out, this can yield undefined behavior if a definition of an inline function is different in release and debug mode, as it then violates the one definition rule.

> what considerations should I care about working with libraries?

That's too broad to be answered on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks. But could you please give me a reference for second question?

Comment: @saeed [This is the best I could come up with.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Dynamic_Link_Libraries)

Comment: Technically it is still undefined behavior, although commonly used. Consider an inline function compiled into both the debug and release parts of the code. That is a violation of the ODR. It can be much worse if 'Debug' has checked iterators and 'Release' does not (these are options in the configuration of the project), which will be a horrible ODR that can crash your application.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "In the entire program, an object or non-inline function cannot have more than one definition" and "Some things, like types, templates, and extern inline functions, can be defined in more than one translation unit." is what Wikipedia says.

Comment: @H2CO3: Wikipedia is not telling you that the standard requires that when it allows for multiple definitions it is undefined behavior if all those definitions don't exactly match. Multiple definitions means that multiple translation units contain the symbol, but the symbol must be exactly the same or else you are hitting undefined behavior. The paragraph is 3.2 paragraph 5, where the requirements for multiple definitions are detailed.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Thanks, I'll have a look at it. (Still this makes no sense, as quite a few other paragraphs of the standard.)

Comment: @H2CO3: It makes quite a lot of sense, the opposite does not. Consider that in two translation units you had `inline int f() { return 1; }` and `inline int f() { return 5; }`. The linker is going to pick one of the definitions and drop the other. If the program depends on the value of `f()`, the result will depend on which is the version that is not discarded by the linker (and you don't want to keep one version of say `std::vector<int>::push_back()` in the program for each translation unit that uses it.

Answer (score 4):

With Visual Studio (2005 and later) classes such as STL containers and iterators will by default be defined differently, and have different memory layout, in debug and release mode. If you mix the debug and release versions of such classes by linking with a static library (or calling a dynamic library whose interface contains such classes) then you will run into trouble.

I believe, but I'm not 100% sure, that with MSVS 2005 and 2008 the code will link, and you will get a mysterious crash at run time, and with MSVS 20010 and 2012 the code will fail to link.

When compiling in debug mode, you can force Visual Studio to use the release versions of STL containers and iterators by defining the macro [_SECURE_SCL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985896%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as 0.